# EditText custom properties android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I want to do the following :

I have an edit text and want to be able to select text from it without showing the soft keyboard and without editing it's content, just to select text to use it in another screen

N.B. this edit text is inside dialog box that shown above the activity, the current scenario that it show up the keyboard when open the dialog

I have tried the following

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

I have also used the following code :

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                v.onTouchEvent(event);
                hideSoftKetboard (v);
                return true;
            }
        });

private void hideSoftKetboard (View v){

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm != null) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }       
    }
```

can anyone help please ?

Comment: What is or is not happening?

Comment: If you just want to retrieve the value that has already been entered into the the text field, use the getter method. ie:  myText.getText()

Comment: you want not focus editText so that the keyboard doesn't appear when your dialog pops?

Answer (score 0):

Use setInputType(0); will solve the problem